# Горизонтальная полоса загрузки

Tags: xml, android, анимация, progress-bar

Привет! Пожалуйста, подскажите, как через xml сделать подобную анимацию для горизонтального `ProgressBar` (indeterminate):

[image: Progress]

Например, фон #D0D0D0, цвет полосок #0000FF и угол полосок 60°.

В гугле был, но там одни туториалы по кастомизации "круглых" `ProgressBar`, да и там просто картинку меняют, а мне надо вот так. Буду благодарен за ссылки и советы.

Comment: Обязательно xml? Собственный класс Drawable не подойдет?

Comment: Да, хмл обязателен.

Comment: Возможно, можно что-то придумать с VectorDrawable из android 5.0.
С остальными это либо невозможно, либо drawable в xml нужно в такую позу поставить, что самому тошно станет.
А зачем именно xml?

Comment: @lsillarionov, VectorDrawable из 5.0 не подойдёт, мне нужна поддержка 4.0. Xml нужен, очевидно, чтобы не делать велосипеды и костыли на Java.